# Where i can find the Microsoft access data base engine registry key in local machine

Tags: registry

I am adding the Microsoft Access Data base engine as prerequisite to my installation in install shield but it always run although the software is already install in machine.So, i am adding condition to install shield to run the prerequisite i need registry key for that purpose.
Where i can find the Microsoft access data base engine registry key in local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You will deal with the system registry to get the right base node of the registry, this change from x64 systems to x86.

Here is the key path

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Access\InstallRoot`

Where **16.0** is the office installed version.

So you will have to loop through all the Office versions `11.0,12.0,14.0,15.0,16.0`

As 2019 just came out I guess it would be 17.0, I hope someone will edit my answer with the correct version of **Office 2019**

Answer (score 0):

This path will determine if MS Access Runtime exists. 
64 Bit O.S will have
RegKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\MSACCESS.EXE

32 Bit O.S will have 
RegKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\MSACCESS.EXE